# Docker ExpressJS public folder volume

Tags: docker, express, dockerfile, docker-volume

I want to create a volume for my "public" folder on Docker on Express App. Because when users upload pictures, I save them to "public/uploads", but when I make changes on code, and have to rebuild with `docker-compose run --build`, I lose all these images.

I tried to find a way to create a volume but I don't know how to link it.

My Dockerfile only consist of these:

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My goal is to serve uploaded images from "public/uploads", and don't get them removed upon `docker-compose run --build`.

Comment: Have you read the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ ?  There are lots of examples there.  Are you having a problem creating a volume, or have a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), you can use the `--mount` flag:

```
//Dockerfile

FROM node:8.10.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# RUN npm ci --only=production

RUN --mount=target=/some_location_in_file_system,type=bind,source=public/uploads

COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have been blind to miss that. But could you clarify for me what target parameter stands for exactly? I assume source is the path which I want to keep in a separate volume.

Comment: Yeah exactly. As I wrote in the code, the target is the location in your file system. Play with it a little bit and you will get it working! Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: A Docker image cannot specify that it uses a specific host directory at runtime.  There is a `docker run --mount` option, but that's a runtime option, not a Dockerfile option.  There's [experimental syntax](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) that matches what you show, but my understanding is that this mount "expires" at the end of the image build sequence and can't specify and arbitrary host path.

Comment: Actually, I solved my problem with modifying `docker-compose.yml`, adding `volumes:
      - ./public/images/uploads:/usr/src/app/public/images/uploads`. Thanks for giving me a starting point.

Edit: Also as @DavidMaze mentioned, your solution actually returned a syntax error, saying invalid flag mount.